# How can I send messages to multiple twitch channels using python 3 Select()?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, select, irc, twitch

I'm trying to create a Twitch bot in Python 3 that will simultaneously monitor and send messages to multiple channels.  I've done this with threads but it's obviously demanding on the CPU and I've read that using Select() is more efficient. The code below allows me to read chat from multiple twitch channels but I'm at a loss for how to identify if the connections returned as writable are the ones I want to write to.

Can I pass in a list of objects that has the socket connection as well as an identifier so I know which ones have come back as writable?

I've read a number of stackoverflow posts related to using select() as well as other sources online but, as a hobbyist coder, I'm having trouble getting my head around this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import socket
import select

HOST = "irc.chat.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667
NICK = "channelname"
PASS = 'oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CHANNEL = "channelname"


def create_sockets(usr_list):
    final_socket_list = []
    channels_first_element = 0
    channels_last_element = len(usr_list)
    for index in range(channels_first_element, channels_last_element):
        channel = usr_list[index]
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.setblocking(False)
        s.send(bytes("PASS " + PASS + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        s.send(bytes("NICK " + NICK + "\r\n", "UTF-8"))
        s.send(bytes("JOIN #" + channel + " \r\n", "UTF-8"))
        s.send(bytes('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership\r\n'.encode('utf-8')))
        s.send(bytes('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands\r\n'.encode('utf-8')))
        s.send(bytes('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags\r\n'.encode('utf-8')))
        final_socket_list.append(s)
    return final_socket_list


def main():
    alive = True
    user_list = ['channelone', 'channeltwo', 'channelthree']
    user_sockets = create_sockets(user_list)

    while alive:
        readable, writable, errorreads = select.select(user_sockets, user_sockets, [])
        if len(readable) != 0:
            for element in readable:
                print(str(element.recv(1024), "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out is that the arguments to `select()` are meant to tell `select()` when to return -- i.e. by including a socket in the first/read_fds argument, you are telling `select()` to return as soon as that socket has incoming-data that is ready-to-read, and by including a socket in the second/write_fds argument, you are telling `select()` to return as soon as that socket has buffer-space-ready-to-write-to.

Because of that, it's important (if you want to be CPU-efficient) to only include a socket in `select()`'s second/write_fds argument if you have data that you want to send to that socket as soon as there is space available in that socket's outgoing-data-buffer.  If you just always pass all of your sockets to the `write_fds` argument (as you are currently doing in the posted code), then `select()` will pretty much always return immediately (because sockets typically almost always have buffer space available to write to), and you'll end up spinning the CPU at near 100% usage, which is very inefficient.

Note that for a light-duty server that is using blocking TCP sockets, it's usually sufficient to simply always pass `[]` as the second argument to `select()`, on the assumption that you will never actually fill any socket's outgoing-data-buffer (and if you do, that the next `send()` call on that socket will simply block until there is buffer space available, and that's okay).  If you want to use non-blocking sockets, you can either make the simplifying assumption that no socket's outgoing-data-buffer will ever become full (in which case passing `[]` to the write_fds argument is fine), or to be 100% robust you'll need to include your own per-socket outgoing-data FIFO queue, and include each socket in the write_fds argument only-if its FIFO queue is non-empty, and when the socket indicates it is ready-for-write, `send()` as many bytes as you can from the head of the socket's FIFO queue.

As for which sockets are the ones you want to write to, that's going to depend entirely on what your app is trying to do, and probably won't depend on which sockets have selected as writeable.  Most programs include a [Dictionary](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) (or some other similar lookup mechanism) for quickly determining which data-object corresponds to a given socket, so when a socket `select()'s` as ready-for-read you can figure out which data-object the data coming from that socket should be viewed as "coming from".  You can then write to any sockets you need to write to, in response.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll have to digest this. :)